# Grad school admissions - I am going to apply to both Physical therapy and Occupational therapy masters - need advice

Tags: graduate-admissions

I have a 3.1 gpa from UW Madison with a BA.  I did go to two schools before this. I did really terribly at the first school as I was depressed. I came away from that first school with a 1.3 gpa.  This first school was 19 years ago - literally 19 years ago.

The school says I need to input all of my transcripts.  Could i get away with not inputting my transcripts from that first school? Is the process of sorting the transcripts really meticulous?  would i get caught?

I actually applied and got into an accounting masters program without inputting all my transcripts before(never finished the program)... But these OT and PT programs are really competitive and I'm more worried they go over the transcripts with a fine tooth comb... any one with experience in college masters admissions - advice?

Comment: Also see [What are some of the serious consequences that someone can suffer if they omit part of their academic record on their application for admission?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/82275/11365)

Comment: If you read up on the what the PT and OT professions are looking for in their members, one of the big ones is integrity. Does hiding your past academic performance sound like something they'd look positively on? And yes, it would come out eventually. Better to include that information with an explanation, than to hide it and have none.

Comment: Imagine yourself ten years from now, sitting on an admissions committee or a hiring committee.  You will look at someone's ancient, embarrassing transcript with compassion, right?  And people in PT and OT go into those fields because they have a lot of compassion, right?  There is no need to panic.  Take a few deep breaths and write a paragraph about the extenuating circumstances, using a very neutral tone.  Then focus your mind on how the committee will view your *good* transcript, and then take a look at all the job ads for OTs.  Where I live, the shortage of OTS...

Comment: is worse than the shortage of ANYTHING else.